# Netbeans undeploys when using netbeans.deploy

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, netbeans

I created a custom netbeans action using xml below.

```
<action>
    <actionName>CUSTOM-mvn redeploy</actionName>
    <displayName>mvn redeploy</displayName>
    <properties>
        <netbeans.deploy>true</netbeans.deploy>
        <netbeans.deploy.debugmode>true</netbeans.deploy.debugmode>
    </properties>
    <goals>
        <goal>compile</goal>
        <goal>war:exploded</goal>
        <goal>tomcat7:redeploy</goal>
    </goals>
</action>
```

Problem is it undeploys the war when netbeans.deploy element is used.

```
tomcatManager status code:200, ReasonPhrase:OK
OK - Deployed application at context path /myservice
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD SUCCESS
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 25.510 s
Finished at: 2015-07-28T14:51:21+08:00
Final Memory: 37M/367M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
NetBeans: Deploying on Apache Tomcat or TomEE
    profile mode: false
    debug mode: true
    force redeploy: true
<b>Undeploying ...
undeploy?path=/myservice
OK - Undeployed application at context path /myservice
```

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who might need this. Somehow I got this resolved by adding a profile in your pom.xml. The profile you added will then become a configuration. Add your custom actions to that configuration

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
    <id>dev</id>
    <build>
        <finalName>myservice</finalName>
    </build>
</profile>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which version of Netbeans the author was using but, as of Netbeans 12.2, see: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-5143.